# how to do a custom segue to particular tab of TabViewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

On click of a button ,i want to navigate to second tab of tabviewcontroller being in  a particular viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically set the specific tabbar using:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender{
  [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```